# Itext pdf deferred signing results in pdf with invalid signature

Tags: pdf, itext, digital-signature

As part of my research for client/server pdf signing , i have tested itext pdf deferred signing example. Unfortunately my resulting pdf ie output of merged empty signature pdf and hash value shows invalid signature.

My code snippets follows

```
 class MyExternalSignatureContainer implements ExternalSignatureContainer {
    protected byte[] sig;
    protected Certificate[] chain;
    public MyExternalSignatureContainer(byte[] sig,Certificate[] chain) {
        this.sig = sig;
        this.chain=chain;
    }
    public byte[] sign(InputStream is)throws GeneralSecurityException  {

        return sig;
    }


public byte[] emptySignature_hash(String src, String dest, String fieldname, Certificate[] chain) throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, fieldname);
        appearance.setCertificate(chain[0]);
        ExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        MakeSignature.signExternalContainer(appearance, external, 8192);
        InputStream inp = appearance.getRangeStream();   
        BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, "SHA256", null, digest, false);
        byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(inp, digest.getMessageDigest("SHA256"));
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1=cal;
        System.out.println(cal);
        byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, cal, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);

        return(sh);
    }

public byte[] signed_hash(byte[] hash, PrivateKey pk, Certificate[] chain)throws GeneralSecurityException{
        PrivateKeySignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA256", "SunPKCS11-eToken");
        byte[] extSignature = signature.sign(hash);
        //return extSignature;
       BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String hashAlgorithm = signature.getHashAlgorithm();
        System.out.println(hashAlgorithm);
        PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, "SHA256", null, digest, false);
        sgn.setExternalDigest(extSignature, null, signature.getEncryptionAlgorithm());
    return sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(hash, cal1, null, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);

        }

 public void createSignature(String src, String dest, String fieldname,byte[] hash, PrivateKey pk, Certificate[] chain) throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    ExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(hash,chain);
    MakeSignature.signDeferred(reader, fieldname, os, external);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, DocumentException {

byte[] hh = app.emptySignature_hash(SRC, TEMP, "sig1", chain);
                byte[] hh_sign = (app.signed_hash(hh,  pk,  chain));
                app.createSignature(TEMP, DEST1, "sig1",hh_sign, pk, chain);

}
```

something went wrong . i could not figure out. searched a lot for tutorials of the same.

I am using pkcss11 usb token for signing

Comment: You appear to use a very old iText version: There has been no `Calendar` parameter in the `PdfPKCS7` methods `getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes` and `getEncodedPKCS7` since 2015...

Comment: I used your code but not working, can you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59497941/itext-signing-pdf-using-external-signature-with-pki-sim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your architecture is wrong insofar as you use the `PdfSignatureAppearance appearance` after running `MakeSignature.signExternalContainer` for it. Both `signExternalContainer` and the `signDetached` overloads in `MakeSignature` close the underlying `PdfStamper`, `PdfSignatureAppearance`, and `PdfReader` instances.

Thus, when you do the following in your method `emptySignature_hash`

```
    MakeSignature.signExternalContainer(appearance, external, 8192);
    InputStream inp = appearance.getRangeStream();
```

your `inp` may not necessarily contain anything sensible.

Instead you should access the byte ranges to sign in your `external` object, it retrieves it as parameter of its `sign` method. Simple refactor your hash calculation into that method and store the calculated hash in a member of that container to retrieve it in `emptySignature_hash`.

As you have not shared an example result of your signing code, I cannot try to determine whether there also are other issues in your signing.

Comment: i changed the following methods and now it is working

Answer (score 2):

it was my mistake.
i modified the emptySignature_hash method and signed_hash as follows and  now it is working fine.

emptySignature_hash method return only digest not authenticatedbytes

```
public byte[] emptySignature_hash(String src, String dest, String fieldname, Certificate[] chain) throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, fieldname);
        appearance.setCertificate(chain[0]);
        ExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        MakeSignature.signExternalContainer(appearance, external, 8192);



        InputStream inp = appearance.getRangeStream();  

        BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();


         byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(inp, digest.getMessageDigest("SHA256"));
         return hash;

    }




public byte[] signed_hash(byte[] hash, PrivateKey pk, Certificate[] chain)throws GeneralSecurityException{
        PrivateKeySignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA256", "SunPKCS11-eToken");
       BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String hashAlgorithm = signature.getHashAlgorithm();
        System.out.println(hashAlgorithm);
        PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, "SHA256", null, digest, false);

        byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, cal, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
        byte[] extSignature = signature.sign(sh);

        System.out.println(signature.getEncryptionAlgorithm());
        sgn.setExternalDigest(extSignature, null, signature.getEncryptionAlgorithm());
    return sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(hash, cal, null, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);

        }
```

i think the problem was previously i was returning getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes of hash in emptysignature_hash method.

And in signed_hash() method i was passing authenticatedattributebytes to
sgn.getEncodedPKCS7.