# Itext pdf deferred signing with invalid signature

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature

I encountered the problem of signature verification failure when using itext to sign pdf. I took it as a reference '[itext-pdf-deferred-signing-results-in-pdf-with-invalid-signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505696/itext-pdf-deferred-signing-results-in-pdf-with-invalid-signature)' Modifications were made, but the problem was still not solved

```
 public static void emptySignature(String src, String dest, String fieldname, Certificate[] chain) throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(50, 780, 144, 780), 1, fieldname);
        appearance.setCertificate(chain[0]);
        ExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        MakeSignature.signExternalContainer(appearance, external, 8192);
        InputStream inp = appearance.getRangeStream();
        BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(inp, digest.getMessageDigest("SHA256"));
//I need to pass this hash value to a third-party system and provide them with the generated signed hash for verification.
        System.out.println("Hash: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hash));
    }

    public static void createSignature(String src, String dest, String fieldname, PrivateKey pk, Certificate[] chain) throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        ExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(pk, chain);
        MakeSignature.signDeferred(reader, fieldname, os, external);
    }
```

main

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        //1.get temp empty file
        emptySignature("mypdf.pdf", "temp.pdf", "", null);//before deferred signing I can not get chain? How can I use this argument?
        //2.get cert from third party system
        Certificate[] cert = getCert();
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        ks.load(new FileInputStream("aaa.p12"), "ogcio".toCharArray());
        String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();
        PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, "ogcio".toCharArray());
        createSignature("temp.pdf", "result.pdf", "", pk, cert);
    }
```

MyExternalSignatureContainer

```
public class MyExternalSignatureContainer implements ExternalSignatureContainer {
    protected PrivateKey pk;
    protected Certificate[] chain;

    public MyExternalSignatureContainer(PrivateKey pk, Certificate[] chain) {
        this.pk = pk;
        this.chain = chain;
    }

    public byte[] sign(InputStream is) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        try {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            PrivateKeySignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA256", "BC");
            String hashAlgorithm = signature.getHashAlgorithm();
            BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
            PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, hashAlgorithm, null, digest, false);
            byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(is, digest.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm));
            byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS);
            byte[] extSignature = signature.sign(sh);
            sgn.setExternalDigest(extSignature, null, signature.getEncryptionAlgorithm());
            return sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(hash, null, null, null, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(ioe);
        }
    }

    public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
        //signDic.put(PdfName.FILTER, PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE);
        //signDic.put(PdfName.SUBFILTER, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
    }
}
```

I used some code above to do. But the signature is invalid with the message "The document has been altered or corrupted since the signatures was applied."
my pdf:"https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jcisJPvfMEXoLFP9Ku-p6nFXuNe7ICWr/view?usp=sharing"

Comment: The signature does not seem to be generated by the private key associated with the alleged signer certificate. Also the signature has not being generated by the code you shared as that code will run into a null pointer exception early.

Comment: @mkl Well, because I can't get the certificate chain information before deferred signing, I set it to null in the main method. I'm not sure how I should set this parameter before signing it.

Comment: @mkl I found this private key file randomly, and the third-party system does not seem to provide me with this private key file

Comment: *"I can't get the certificate chain information before deferred signing"* - That is unfortunate, the `PdfPKCS7` class expects it before. And depending on your target signature profile you will need it before even with other classes. Alternatively check whether your signing service can also return complete CMS signature containers profiled for PDF use, not merely naked signatures, that would likely remove the need for certificates early.

Comment: @mkl Yes, after asking my signing service, he told me that they would return a signature field, but I do not know how I should use this signature field to sign the certificate into my pdf.In this case, do I need to use other signing methods to sign the pdf

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NCx2GWkHPjsE9NnilfrHFC-xaocn_5eO/view?usp=sharing) This is the field description provided by my signing service @mkl

Comment: You need a service that either allows to retrieve the certificate before the actual signing call, or that returns you a CMS signature container. I cannot see anything in the image you show that indicates that either option is possible.

Comment: This is the integration document given by my signing service. From the above description, does it fail to meet the pre-requirements for signing?[signing service](https://iamsmart.cyberport.hk/documents-forms/guide-for-developer/guide-signing/) @mkl

Comment: *"This is the integration document given by my signing service."* - Hhmmm, the document doesn't look very promising. But it refers to an actual API documentation. Do you have that?

Comment: [ApiSpecification](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c6gXDQ6Y5yuVvQITz_DH0BR6PkBkMhrQ/view)Yes I have the API description document for it. But it seems that the description in the document is similar to the description on its official website. I am currently using the two APIs 6.5.2 and 6.5.5 in the document. I need to generate the hash value of the document before requesting a signature, and then provide the hash of the document to the signing service. The signing service will return me the signature and certificate information. This is probably the process.@mkl

Comment: *"I am currently using the two APIs 6.5.2 and 6.5.5 in the document."* - But those two sections are explicitly about "PDF signing" which I didn't see on the web-site before. And most importantly, 6.5.5 doesn't have the "Base64-encoded signature result string" `signature` in its result but instead the "Base64-encoded PKCS#7 object" `pdfSignature`! "PKCS#7 object" paraphrases "CMS signature container", PKCS#7 is the precursor of CMS.

Comment: Thus, if you use the 6.5.2/6.5.5 API, you can simplify your code considerably, you don't need the certificate anymore, you don't need the `PdfPKCS7` anymore, and your external signature container implementation of `sign` merely needs to hash the content of the `InputStream is` parameter, call the 6.5.2 PDF signing request for that hash, wait for the 6.5.5 callback, and return the `pdfSignature` contents (after base64 decoding).

Comment: I'm so sorry, there is something wrong with what I described before. I am not using 6.5.5. The API I am using now is 6.5.2. After requesting this API, my Signing Service will return to me a BusinessId, which is associated with the user in the Signing Service. After the mobile phone performs the authorized signature operation, the Signing Service will call back my API and return the signature and cert to me. (API 6.5.4)@mkl

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The 6.5.4 is the callback for 6.5.1. 6.5.5 is the callback for 6.5.2. So if you're using 6.5.2 (which is specified to use the https://<iAM_Smart_domain>/api/v1/account/pdfsigning/initiateRequest URL - **../pdfsigning/..**!), the callback you have to receive is the 6.5.5 callback. If you receive a 6.5.4 callback, there is an error in the server.

Comment: Have you tried a 6.5.2 request to the ../pdfsigning/.. URL and analyzed the callback?

Comment: Yes, I think there may be a problem with the signing service's callback to me. I will contact the signing service again to confirm. If I use the callback of 6.5.4, how should I sign the PDF? Can you give me a demo? Thank you so much@mkl

Comment: The callback I currently receive from 6.5.5 is as follows:[result.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12-h1Rq_asC4KCrQFVRbgPQV5YR5DbZxy/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hhmmm, that is weird. Have you double-checked that you use the .../PDF signing/... URL? A callback of the 6.5.4 type is not really useful for PDF signing.

Comment: Okay, I'll contact the Signing Service again and ask them how to get the 6.5.5 callback. However, the PKCS7 file provided in 6.5.5 does not have a private key. How can I sign this certificate to pdf without a private key? Can you help provide a demo?@mkl

Comment: The PKCS7 file is a signature container which holds both the certificate and the signature. According to your API spec this is exactly what is needed for PDF signing. Let's hope the spec is up-to-date and the service has implemented this part of the API.

Comment: Yes, the link is to the base64 encoded sample PKCS7 file provided by Signing Service, but I still have no idea about signing this file to pdf, do you have any good suggestions?[pkcs7 file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CsUbUgQuuId_eoSs8NVEb3DTI6KtDKjf/view?usp=sharing) @mkl

Comment: Yes, the file looks good. It even contains a digital time stamp. And yes, I have an idea how to change your code to make use of a pkcs7 file returned from your service. I merely cannot test it, though, as I have no access to the iAM Smart services. I'll write an answer later, maybe tomorrow.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your help, hope to get your answer @mkl

Comment: Is there any progress now? At present, I still have no idea about this problem. Is there any example that can be provided for reference @mkl

Comment: I have a preliminary version here. Unfortunately since this morning Adobe Acrobat doesn't start on my system anymore, so I cannot do any tests with Acrobat. I'll write an answer nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support, I can't wait to get your answer. Also, I can help with testing if possible.@mkl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing code couldn't successfully sign the PDF as it needed the signer certificate before signing while the iAM Smart signing service (for which the code eventually shall be used) provides the certificate only together with the signature.

Such signing services that return the signer certificate only together with the signature bytes are difficult to use for PDF signatures in general because most CMS signature container generators expect to have access to all data (except obviously the signature bytes) before starting to assemble the to-be-signed attributes and requesting a signature for them. For the special case of PAdES PDF signatures they even cannot be used at all as PAdES baseline signatures require information about the signer certificate in the to-be-signed attributes.

In comments it fortunately turned out that the iAM Smart service also provides the functionality of returning a full PKCS#7 object (i.e. CMS signature container) explicitly profiled for PDF signing. If one uses this service functionality, one can simplify the existing code and use it to sign PDFs with iText as follows:

```
File origFile = new File("deferredContainerSigningOriginal.pdf");
File tempFile = new File("deferredContainerSigningTemp.pdf");
File resultFile = new File("deferredContainerSigningResult.pdf");
String fieldName = "Signature";

byte[] hash = null;

try (
    OutputStream tempOutput = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)
) {
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(origFile.getPath());
    hash = prepareAndHashForSigning(pdfReader, tempOutput, fieldName);
}

// execute your signature container request for the calculated hash here 
byte[] signatureContainer = retrievePkcs7ContainerForHash(hash);

try (
    OutputStream resultOutput = new FileOutputStream(resultFile)
) {
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(tempFile.getPath());
    injectPkcs7Container(pdfReader, resultOutput, fieldName, signatureContainer);
}
```

using the following helper methods and class:

```
/**
 * This method adds a signature field to the given PDF and sets its value signature
 * dictionary. The placeholder for the signature container therein is filled with 0s.
 * 
 * @return the hash of the signed byte ranges of the added signature.
 * @see #testExternalSignatureContainer()
 */
byte[] prepareAndHashForSigning(PdfReader pdfReader, OutputStream outputStream, String fieldName) throws DocumentException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(pdfReader, outputStream, (char) 0);
    PdfSignatureAppearance pdfSignatureAppearance = pdfStamper.getSignatureAppearance();
    pdfSignatureAppearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(50, 680, 144, 780), 1, fieldName);

    ExternalSignatureContainer blankContainer = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
    MakeSignature.signExternalContainer(pdfSignatureAppearance, blankContainer, 12000);
    InputStream rangeStream = pdfSignatureAppearance.getRangeStream();
    BouncyCastleDigest bouncyCastleDigest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(rangeStream, bouncyCastleDigest.getMessageDigest("SHA256"));
    return hash;
}

/**
 * This method sets the signature container placeholder in the signature dictionary
 * value of the signature field with the given name.
 * 
 * @see #testExternalSignatureContainer()
 */
void injectPkcs7Container(PdfReader pdfReader, OutputStream outputStream, String fieldName, byte[] signatureContainer) throws DocumentException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    ExternalSignatureContainer injectingContainer = new InjectingSignatureContainer(signatureContainer);
    MakeSignature.signDeferred(pdfReader, fieldName, outputStream, injectingContainer);
}

/**
 * This is a dummy method that returns the given hash itself instead of a signature
 * container for it. Obviously, it is not for production purposes.
 * 
 * @see #testExternalSignatureContainer()
 */
byte[] retrievePkcs7ContainerForHash(byte[] hash) {
    return hash;
}

/**
 * This {@link ExternalSignatureContainer} implementation returns a pre-generated
 * byte array in its {@link #sign(InputStream)} method.
 */
static class InjectingSignatureContainer implements ExternalSignatureContainer {
    final byte[] signatureContainer;

    public InjectingSignatureContainer(byte[] signatureContainer) {
        this.signatureContainer = signatureContainer;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] sign(InputStream data) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        return signatureContainer;
    }

    @Override
    public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
    }
}
```

*([CreateDeferredSignature](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/signature/CreateDeferredSignature.java) test)*

This all is pretty similar to your code which already implemented a number of correct concepts but which suffered from the background of eventually having to use an inappropriate signing service functionality.

Beware, I additionally adapted some constants, in particular I increased the size reserved for the signature container from your 8192 to 12000 (because the example signature container you provided already is 10462 large) and I changed the coordinates of the rectangle as yours had height 0.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I tried using the answer you provided and now I can successfully sign the pdf and the signed file is also verified @mkl

Comment: Great! Hope everything progresses smoothly from here on.