# Sign PDF hash using java and iText

Tags: java, pdf, hash, itext, digital-signature

I have an application that generates a PDF, and that needs to be signed.

We have not the certificates to sign the document, because they're in a HSM, and the only way we could make use of the certificates is using a webservice.

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    reader.setAppendable(true);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, fout, '\0');
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance  = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();

    appearance.setReason("Test");
    appearance.setLocation("footer");
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200), 1, null);
    appearance.setCertificate(certChain[0]);

    PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
    dic.setReason(appearance.getReason());
    dic.setLocation(appearance.getLocation());
    dic.setContact(appearance.getContact());
    dic.setDate(new PdfDate(appearance.getSignDate()));
    appearance.setCryptoDictionary(dic);

    HashMap<PdfName, Integer> exc = new HashMap<PdfName, Integer>();
    exc.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new Integer(8192 * 2 + 2));
    appearance.preClose(exc);

    ExternalDigest externalDigest = new ExternalDigest()
    {
        public MessageDigest getMessageDigest(String hashAlgorithm) throws GeneralSecurityException
        {
            return DigestAlgorithms.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm, null);
        }
    };

    PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, certChain, "SHA256", null, externalDigest, false);
    InputStream data = appearance.getRangeStream();
    byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, externalDigest.getMessageDigest("SHA256"));
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, cal, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
    sh = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA256", "BC").digest(sh);

    String hashPdf = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(sh));

    String hashSignat = hashPdf;
```

This is our code, first, we get the signature appearance, and calculate the hash

In this point, we have the hash code of the document. Then we send the hash to the webservice, and we get the signed hash code.

Finally, we put the signed hash to the PDF:

```
    sgn.setExternalDigest(Base64.decode(hashSignat), null, "RSA");
    byte[] encodedSign = sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(hash, cal, null, null, 
    null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
    byte[] paddedSig = new byte[8192];
    System.arraycopy(encodedSign, 0, paddedSig, 0, 
    encodedSign.length);

    PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary();
    dic2.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(paddedSig).setHexWriting(true));

    appearance.close(dic2);
```

In this point, we get a PDF signed, but with an invalid signature. Adobe says that "Document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed".

I have gone through [Sign PDF using an external service and iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717704/sign-pdf-using-an-external-service-and-itext/28940903#28940903), [PDF signature itext pkcs7 multi sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706696/pdf-signature-itext-pkcs7-multi-sign) and [Is it possible to sign a PDF document with hash and signed hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44254524/is-it-possible-to-sign-a-pdf-document-with-hash-and-signed-hash) but no luck.

Comment: iText has many limitations, I would suggest try using PDFlib

Comment: @Dhanraj *"iText has many limitations, I would suggest try using PDFlib"* - How exactly does that help anyone to *sign PDF hash using java and iText* which this question is about? Not at all I'd say.

Comment: Priyanka, please share a sample signed PDF for analysis.

Comment: @mkl here you can get one 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13wpirorpEnj2dKi7ZTo76pYhx9Hfiz5v/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hhmmm, the actually signed hash is `1134ED96F42AC7352E546BE0E906C0BF5D44229AEAFAC39145DB40A0BB7E817B` which should be the hash of the authenticated attributes but their hash is `E7101D9770ABF5E58D43670AAC6E9418265AE80F74B3BDFB67911C0CC5D5D949`. The signed byte ranges hash is `D7917CF3BA9FE5D5B626ED825965D699F7C54DBBF9F18DECE18EF8DD36DC4C28`, so its not this hash, either. So I don't really know the hash of what that `11...` is. You might want to share more code of what happens between `String hashSignat = hashPdf` and `sgn.setExternalDigest(Base64.decode(hashSignat), null, "RSA")`...

Comment: Thank you so much @mkl for help. Actually, the encoding utility on web service was different due to which the decoded hash value was wrong and MessageDigest(sh = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA256", "BC").digest(sh);) is not needed. this line was giving the wrong hash.

Comment: @mkl but here when I am signing file which is already signed is getting sign but with an invalid signature. its showing "the signature byte range is invalid". Please help me with this. And i am really thankfull to your comment. it really helped me.

Comment: For signing already signed pdfs use the append mode. For that you need a different `PdfStamper.createSignature` overload with one more parameter, a `boolean`, which you set to `true`.

Comment: Shall I create an actual answer from all the comments here for you to accept?

Comment: Yes. that will be a great thing. @mkl I m just confused that why the value of byte "sh" is getting change for the same file every time? actually, I want to store the hash value of the file. is it because of "cal"?

Comment: The `cal` with the signing time is just one part, the PDF also contains a modification date and a unique revision ID in the hashed data.

Comment: so @mkl can I get the hash at a time and store it in db and sign the hash later and append in pdf?

Comment: You either have to keep the `stamper` and `appearance` open for the time, or you have to keep the prepared file, or you have to patch iText to allow you to set fixed values for signing time, manipulation time, and id.

Comment: @mkl 1st option is not possible for me. I didn't get the 2nd 3rd option. can you elaborate both or give any reference which I can refer?

Comment: I get the impression you forgot to mention some boundary conditions of your task... :) I'll try and have a look, most likely sometime on Monday or Tuesday.

Comment: yah. I m sorry. It will be great if you can help me with this. Actually, I will have web service which will provide the hash which will save in DB, and then will send the hash to another service which will sign the hash and then save it on DB. and then will fetch signed hash from DB and append in pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The example file

You shared an [example file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13wpirorpEnj2dKi7ZTo76pYhx9Hfiz5v/view?usp=sharing) signed by your code in a comment to your question.

An analysis of that file (executed using the [AnalyzeSignatures](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/signature/analyze/AnalyzeSignatures.java#L333) test `testPriyankaSignatureSampleinformedconsent_Signed`) shows that the actually signed hash is

```
1134ED96F42AC7352E546BE0E906C0BF5D44229AEAFAC39145DB40A0BB7E817B
```

which should be the hash of the authenticated attributes but their hash is

```
E7101D9770ABF5E58D43670AAC6E9418265AE80F74B3BDFB67911C0CC5D5D949.
```

The signed byte ranges hash is

```
D7917CF3BA9FE5D5B626ED825965D699F7C54DBBF9F18DECE18EF8DD36DC4C28,
```

so its not this hash, either. Thus it was not clear where that signed hash came from.

It eventually turned out that

> the encoding utility on web service was different due to which the decoded hash value was wrong and `MessageDigest(sh = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA256", "BC").digest(sh);)` is not needed. this line was giving the wrong hash.

#### Signing previously signed files

Thereafter a new issue popped up:

> when I am signing file which is already signed is getting sign but with an invalid signature. its showing "the signature byte range is invalid".

For signing already signed pdfs you have to use the **append mode**. For that you need a different `PdfStamper.createSignature` overload with one more parameter, a `boolean`, which you set to `true`.

The reason is that usually (i.e. without activating the **append mode**) iText reorganizes the internal PDF structures and drops unused objects. In already signed PDFs this usually moves the position of the (already existing) signature which invalidates the signature structure. Using **append mode**, though, iText keeps the original PDF bytes as they were and only appends new data.

#### Changing hashes

> I m just confused that why the value of byte "sh" is getting change for the same file every time? actually, I want to store the hash value of the file. is it because of "cal"?

Indeed, each time you start manipulating a PDF, the result gets a new unique ID. Furthermore, the modification time is stored. And in case of a signing use case, also the signing time differs.

> can I get the hash at a time and store it in db and sign the hash later and append in pdf?

You either have to

- keep the stamper and appearance open for the time, or you have to
- keep the prepared file, or you have to
- patch iText to allow you to set fixed values for signing time, manipulation time, and id.

> 1st option is not possible for me. I didn't get the 2nd 3rd option. can you elaborate both or give any reference which I can refer?

#### Patching iText to enforce fixed hashes for each file

Ok, first off the third option, patching iText, usually is something you don't want to do because it makes incorporating later iText updates difficult.

OpenPdf (an older iText fork) contains a patch adding `EnforcedModificationDate`, `OverrideFileId`, and `IncludeFileID` properties to `PdfStamper`. (`PdfSignatureAppearance` already has a `SignDate` property.) This patch has been applied to allow eSignature DSS to use OpenPdf in its signing process (which also includes creating the signed PDF twice and so requires fixed hash values).

You might not want to switch to this old iText fork because it misses many fixes and new options of newer iText versions.

#### Keeping the already prepared file

Thus, you probably should instead keep the originally created file with an empty signature, e.g. in some temporary folder, and apply **deferred signing** as soon as you retrieve the final signature.

This essentially is what the iText example [C4_09_DeferredSigning](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I5JS/repos/tutorial/browse/signatures/src/main/java/signatures/chapter4/C4_09_DeferredSigning.java) is all about, it first creates an intermediary PDF with everything in it, only the signatrue bytes are missing:

```
public void emptySignature(String src, String dest, String fieldname, Certificate[] chain) throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, fieldname);
    appearance.setCertificate(chain[0]);
    ExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
    MakeSignature.signExternalContainer(appearance, external, 8192);
}
```

Only in a second step an actual signature is injected:

```
public void createSignature(String src, String dest, String fieldname, PrivateKey pk, Certificate[] chain) throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
    
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    ExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(pk, chain);
    MakeSignature.signDeferred(reader, fieldname, os, external);
}
```

using

```
class MyExternalSignatureContainer implements ExternalSignatureContainer {

    protected PrivateKey pk;
    protected Certificate[] chain;
    
    public MyExternalSignatureContainer(PrivateKey pk, Certificate[] chain) {
        this.pk = pk;
        this.chain = chain;
    }
    
    public byte[] sign(InputStream is) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        try {
            PrivateKeySignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA256", "BC");
            String hashAlgorithm = signature.getHashAlgorithm();
            BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
            PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, hashAlgorithm, null, digest, false);
            byte hash[] = DigestAlgorithms.digest(is, digest.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm));
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, cal, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
            byte[] extSignature = signature.sign(sh);
            sgn.setExternalDigest(extSignature, null, signature.getEncryptionAlgorithm());
            return sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(hash, cal, null, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(ioe);
        }
    }

    public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
    }
    
}
```

Here the has is calculated in the second step, but you don't need to do so, you can

- already calculate it in the first step by not using the original `ExternalBlankSignatureContainer` as in `emptySignature()` above but instead extending it to calculate the hash as `MyExternalSignatureContainer` does,
- storing this value in your database, and
- (as soon as you retrieve the signature) injecting that signature using a variant of `MyExternalSignatureContainer` that does not calculate the hash but instead injects exactly the returned signature.

Comment: Hi @mkl, I am bit confused with the following steps:- already calculate it in the first step by not using the original ExternalBlankSignatureContainer as in emptySignature() above but instead extending it to calculate the hash as MyExternalSignatureContainer does,
storing this value in your database, and
(as soon as you retrieve the signature) injecting that signature using a variant of MyExternalSignatureContainer that does not calculate the hash but instead injects exactly the returned signature.
In deferred signature we need private key and I will not have access of private key

Comment: *"I am bit confused"* - By what exactly? *"In deferred signature we need private key and I will not have access of private key"* - in that example, yes. Obviously you are expected to adjust the example to match your use case...

Comment: Thank you @mkl. Thanks a lot. it took me some time to understand but this code helped me a lot. thank you so much. :) ... I referred the following link which helped me to implement my requirement along with your given solution :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505696/itext-pdf-deferred-signing-results-in-pdf-with-invalid-signature

Comment: This example ( C4_09_DeferredSigning) is always given for external hash signing but actually it is meaningless. You can not use the hash retrieved in the first step.
In the real use case, hash should be retrieved while the empty signature and user signs this hash on his/her desk and the signed hash must be used in the second step. But unfortunately it is impossible without using the same object.
Patching iText is more interesting for me but how to use that fields?

Comment: @EbruYener *"This example ( C4_09_DeferredSigning) is always given for external hash signing but actually it is meaningless."* - no, it is not meaningless. *"You can not use the hash retrieved in the first step"* - oh yes you can.... simply said, I don't understand what you want to discuss in the comment. Better make it an actual question and describe the issue in your use case in more detail.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed for CSC API integration. This is gold, I'm stealing it thx