# Sign Pdf Using ITextSharp and XML Signature

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, digital-signature, xml-signature

I am trying to sing a pdf using a remote web service which returns a XML signature that consists of `PKCS#1` signature with end users certificate.

I need to use this signature to sign pdf via IText `deferred` signing because the web service works `asynchronously`.

All the IText examples uses `PKCS#7` message format but I am not sure what should I do for XML signature.

**Code That Adds Empty Signature Field and Gets Signable Bytes of Pdf**

```
public static string GetBytesToSign(string unsignedPdf, string tempPdf, string signatureFieldName)
{
    if (File.Exists(tempPdf))
        File.Delete(tempPdf);

    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(unsignedPdf))
    {
        using (FileStream os = File.OpenWrite(tempPdf))
        {
            PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0');
            PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
            appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 250, 400), 1, signatureFieldName);

            IExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);

            MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer(appearance, external, 8192);

            byte[] array = SHA256Managed.Create().ComputeHash(appearance.GetRangeStream());

            return Convert.ToBase64String(array);
        }
    }
}
```

**Code That Opens Temp Pdf And Embeds The Received Signature**

```
public static void EmbedSignature(string tempPdf, string signedPdf, string signatureFieldName, string signature)
{
    byte[] signedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(signature);

    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(tempPdf))
    {
        using (FileStream os = File.OpenWrite(signedPdf))
        {
            IExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(signedBytes);
            MakeSignature.SignDeferred(reader, signatureFieldName, os, external);
        }
    }
}
```

**The returned XML Signature from web service:**

```
<SignatureValue Id="Signature-xxx-SIG">
RMFbYIigsrjYQEc4PCoHMMg8vwz/hYrCjj0IR+835BZZ/TsTMHZhMVnu2KQZi1UL
dWMeuhTxagBmjdBSzGiy1OEdH5r0FM77Of4Zz99o/aAhYqr3qpOETGgNn9GHlphL
5FSPYbNsq2rDHA8FsNdqNdb6qJUZYsfYvuhJaUMstBXeL/dLIT46t7ySCQ7CGjE5
mpD1AG8M+TVWf4ut5tucZuZV9PMQB3tyoarQD5RoUv872RzB5IorcIhLnf+O6E6o
EF0HuGitRhN9bbPgdLaUma5MNjKCaeQTpCXp3KXwi8VoQGd5fpUBZbAKtMpKeCts
RAOk1O4uk/4poic4IGPhDw==
</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>

<KeyValue>
<RSAKeyValue>

<Modulus>
AI5T0zOBBD4i7Cb1v8wDL0+By8i1h2U0HDFQ73/iNBkM9Gd7mUU0i2A9wJTeiktS
IeBU/JLzqVp7vK857dZlrlT9qiH2cNQufh+q2MpNk7wtPcDACVedVkBUNkIgoXBy
g4cGmAYoWBsD2zDXiZXukStjUWws+/xCU0hADIelFONr141zRHindfq86QrDTC7q
bHBtDT7dJckWzaDPHf3Xlej+U/A1x/8kd504VZaFQfAPYBOgGPY918G1HjBtlajR
nyrl10LuV708IHZtAmKmEfdZOeq//9OGZZLh2nJ86b5Fa6XPFhxzLx/ugBS/8GHt
iVYeJOlfHXRl5w2k2Vv/ssU=
</Modulus>

<Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>

</RSAKeyValue>
</KeyValue>

<X509Data>
<X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
</X509Data>

</KeyInfo>
```

When I use the returned `PKCS#1` signature with above code, the signature verification fails with **"Error encountered while BER decoding"**.

Since the `BlankSignatureContainer` created with `ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED` subFilter, I think this is normal. However, I am not sure what filter and subFilter I should use for `PKCS#1`? Or Should / Can I create `PKCS#7` message from `PKCS#1` and user's certificate and use this format instead?

**EDIT 1:**

I can also retrieve the end users certificate before requesting the signature.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns1:MSS_ProfileQueryResponse xmlns:ns1="/mobilesignature/validation/soap">
         <MSS_ProfileResp MinorVersion="1" MajorVersion="1" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns5="http://uri.etsi.org/TS102204/v1.1.2#">
            <ns5:AP_Info Instant="2017-09-16T04:54:43.260Z" AP_PWD="turkcell123" AP_TransID="_1371012883260" AP_ID="http://turkcell.com.tr"/>
            <ns5:MSSP_Info Instant="2017-09-16T13:33:36.316+02:00">
               <ns5:MSSP_ID/>
            </ns5:MSSP_Info>
            <ns5:SignatureProfile>
               <ns5:mssURI>http://MobileSignature/profile2</ns5:mssURI>
               <ns5:CertIssuerDN> Mobil NES Hizmet Saglayicisi S2</ns5:CertIssuerDN>
               <ns5:CertSerialNumber>71408272140747005781907792964830346324</ns5:CertSerialNumber>
               <ns5:CertHash>
                  <ns5:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                  <ns5:DigestValue>e1yKlaPIU95phxxYvrUsmSQDpKqKU60/b+a8BLw1wNM=</ns5:DigestValue>
               </ns5:CertHash>
               <ns5:msspUrl>http://localhost</ns5:msspUrl>
               <ns5:certIssuerDN-DER>MG8xCzAJBgNVBAYTAlRSMSgwJgYDVQQKDB9FbGVrdHJvbmlrIEJpbGdpIEd1dmVubGlnaSBBLlMuMTYwNAYDVQQDDC1URVNUIFR1cmtjZWxsIE1vYmlsIE5FUyBIaXptZXQgU2FnbGF5aWNpc2kgUzI=</ns5:certIssuerDN-DER>
            </ns5:SignatureProfile>
            <ns5:Status>
               <ns5:StatusCode Value="100"/>
               <ns5:StatusMessage>REQUEST_OK</ns5:StatusMessage>
            </ns5:Status>
         </MSS_ProfileResp>
      </ns1:MSS_ProfileQueryResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**EDIT 2:**

I have updated my signing code to construct a CMS. However, the resulting hash value to be signed is 77 bytes. The web service excepts 32 bytes SHA256 hashed data.

```
public static byte[] GetBytesToSign(string unsignedPdf, string tempPdf, string signatureFieldName, byte[] x509Signature)
{
    if (File.Exists(tempPdf))
        File.Delete(tempPdf);

    var chain = new List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate>
    {
        Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(new X509Certificate2(x509Signature))
    };

    Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate certificate = chain.ElementAt(0);

    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(unsignedPdf))
    {
        using (FileStream os = File.OpenWrite(tempPdf))
        {
            PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0');

            PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;

            appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 250, 400), 1, signatureFieldName);

            appearance.Certificate = chain[0];

            IExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);

            MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer(appearance, external, 8192);

            Stream data = appearance.GetRangeStream();

            byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, "SHA256");

            var signature = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, "SHA256", false);

            byte[] signatureHash = signature.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);

            _signature = signature;
            _apperance = appearance;
            _hash = hash;
            _signatureHash = signatureHash;

            return signatureHash;
        }
    }
}

public static void EmbedSignature(string tempPdf, string signedPdf, string signatureFieldName, byte[] signedBytes)
{
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(tempPdf))
    {
        using (FileStream os = File.OpenWrite(signedPdf))
        {
            _signature.SetExternalDigest(signedBytes, null, "RSA");

            byte[] encodedSignature = _signature.GetEncodedPKCS7(_hash, null, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);

            IExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(encodedSignature);

            MakeSignature.SignDeferred(reader, signatureFieldName, os, external);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all,  pure PKCS#1 signatures in PDFs should not be used, modern standards only work with CMS (PKCS#7) containers. Second: in either case you need the signer certificate before calling the service to sign some hash because the signer identity is to be referenced in the signed data.

Comment: By *either case* I mean either if you try to use pure PKCS#1 signatures in the pdf or you try and use the PKCS#1 signatures returned by your service to build a CMS container (as ESS support nowadays is a must). If the service returns a proper CMS container, you don't necessarily need to know the signer identity in advance.

Comment: @mkl thanks. When I sent the hash of the document to web service, web service encrypts the hash using the end users private key (end user signs using their mobile sim card). Sorry but I didn't understand which certificate of the user I need before calling the service? According to service documentation the returned data is in the RFC3275 XML sig. format which consists of PKCS#1 sig. and end users certificate. So can I sign the documen with this XML based signature or do i need to create a CMS using this XML? Unfortunately, web service only returns XML based sig. for Base64 encoded hashes.

Comment: I updated my question as how to sign pdf using xml signature instead of pkcs#1 signature.

Comment: *"Sorry but I didn't understand which certificate of the user I need before calling the service?"* - the one associated with the private key the service used. The one you currently retrieve as part of answer of the service. If the service always uses the same certificate,  you can store that and use. If the service uses different ones in an unpredictable manner, it becomes difficult.

Comment: *"So can I sign the documen with this XML based signature or do i need to create a CMS using this XML?"* - as mentioned above, you need to know the end user certificate before calling the service, but then you can either use the pure PKCS#1 signature directly or built a CMS signature container from it. The latter would be better as newer standards like PAdES require the CMS form.

Comment: I am not really familiar with digital signature so thanks a lot for the help. Ok, I find out that I can access to another service "This service enables Application Providers to request end user’s certificate serial number and certificate hash which can be used in constructing the data to be signed. ".  I think the data returned from this service is what I need to built CMS signature container.

I found your answer about simular issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717704/sign-pdf-using-an-external-service-and-itext I will try to build the container and let you know.

Comment: @mkl I have tried to create CMS container using end users certificate but the resulted hash to be sent to service is 77 bytes. Is this normal? The service only accepts 32 byte data. I updated my question with the new code.

Comment: 77 bytes hash is not normal. Probably you don't have the final hash yet but merely the authenticated/signed attributes which you still have to hash. Hard to say without more information. Ah, I just saw your edit. Indeed, you took the `getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes` and thought they were the hash. They are not. Either you or the signing service still has to hash.

Comment: @mkl Yes! I fixed it by hashing the result of getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes. It works now! Thanks a lot. Can you write your comments as answer?

Comment: I will tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(This answer summarizes the evolution of working code in the course of comments and edits to the question.)*

#### Which option does PDF support

The PDF format (the commonly supported ISO 32000-1:2008) specified embedded signatures using either naked PKCS#1 signatures or full PKCS#7/CMS signature containers, cf. section 12.8.3 "Signature Interoperability", in particular

- section 12.8.3.2 "PKCS#1 Signatures" and
- section 12.8.3.3 "PKCS#7 Signatures as used in ISO 32000".

Newer standards, like the ETSI PAdES standards and the new ISO 32000-2:2017, forbid or deprecate the former option. For a new solution that shall not be outdated already on the day it is published, therefore, one should go for the latter choice.

#### Knowing the certificate beforehand

> I am trying to sing a pdf using a remote web service which returns a XML signature that consists of PKCS#1 signature with end users certificate.

If that were all the functionality of the web service, there'd be a problem: Both when embedding a naked PKCS#1 signature and when constructing a PKCS#7 signature container, one needs to know the end entity certificate *before* calling the service to create a signature for a hash because that certificate or a reference to it must be embedded in the signed PDF data or the signed CMS attributes.

(Strictly speaking very basic CMS signature container do not require this but all signature profiles to take seriously do.)

Fortunately it turned out (edit 1) that one

> can access to another service "This service enables Application Providers to request end user’s certificate serial number and certificate hash which can be used in constructing the data to be signed."

#### The code

The OP found iText/Java code for implementing the functionality to sign a PDF with an embedded PKCS#7/CMS signature container based on a signing service as described above (edit 2).

> However, the resulting hash value to be signed is 77 bytes. The web service excepts 32 bytes SHA256 hashed data.

As it turned out, though, those 77 bytes were not the hash of the signed attributes:

```
public static byte[] GetBytesToSign(string unsignedPdf, string tempPdf, string signatureFieldName, byte[] x509Signature)
{
    [...]
    byte[] signatureHash = signature.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
    [...]
    return signatureHash;
}
```

They were the signed attributes bytes. Thus, these bytes merely needed to be hashed to produce the hash to send to the signing service for creating a signature.

Comment: I am integrating with Aadhaar Esign services. In signature request we are passing entire hash of the document as we don't know where to stamp sign(X-y cords) , webservice return PKCS7 (CMS) Signature as base 64 string,  I need to use this response to multiple signature locations, I referred your answer to this question and followed steps but it is showing invalid and altered pdf since signature was applied.

Comment: @Div The web service most likely is easy to integrate by using an iText `ExternalSignatureContainer` interface centered approach. The more relevant problem is *"multiple signature locations"* for a single signature which the PDF specification clearly forbids. There is a way around this which follows the letter of the spec, not the spirit, though. Thus, that way probably eventually will be forbidden, too. More at the [referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55237425/1729265).