# I had some trouble while trying to sign in pdf file with itextsharp, invalid signature

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, digital-signature

I found a lot of code in Stackoverflow and I combined all of them into my case, I tried to find the answer, but after all, I didn't get that. This is the result after I ran my code and opened the PDF file signed.

**The document has been altered or corrupted since the signature was applied.**

This is my Signpdf class, serviceHashSign is the signature I receive from service, it's base string is like this "av5oW5j4P1zHv1PJJb2mdOlvv5DMiUpH+5..." and I converted it to bytes array.

```
class Signpdf
    {

        public static byte[] GetBytesToSign(string unsignedPdf, string tempPdf, string signatureFieldName, List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate> chain, byte[] serviceHashSign)
        {
            if (File.Exists(tempPdf))
                File.Delete(tempPdf);

            //Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate certificate = chain[0];

            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(unsignedPdf))
            {
                using (FileStream os = new FileStream(tempPdf, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                {
                    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0');

                    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
                    
                    appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 250, 400), 1, signatureFieldName);
                    appearance.Certificate = chain[0];
                    appearance.SignDate = DateTime.Now;

                    appearance.Reason = "test";
                    appearance.Location = "test";

                    IExternalSignature es = new RemoteSignature(serviceHashSign);
                    MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, es, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);


                    byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(appearance.GetRangeStream(), "SHA256");
                    var signature = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, "SHA256", false);
                    byte[] sh = signature.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
                    signature.SetExternalDigest(sh, null, "RSA");
                    byte[] encodedSignature = signature.GetEncodedPKCS7(hash, null, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);

                    return encodedSignature;
                }
            }
        }

        public static void EmbedSignature(string tempPdf, string signedPdf, string signatureFieldName, byte[] signedBytes)
        {
            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(tempPdf))
            {
                using (FileStream os = new FileStream(signedPdf, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                {

                    IExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(signedBytes);

                    MakeSignature.SignDeferred(reader, signatureFieldName, os, external);
                }
            }
        }

        private class MyExternalSignatureContainer : IExternalSignatureContainer
        {
            private readonly byte[] signedBytes;

            public MyExternalSignatureContainer(byte[] signedBytes)
            {
                this.signedBytes = signedBytes;
            }

            public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
            {
                return signedBytes;
            }

            public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic)
            {
            }
        }
```

And here is the RemoteSignature class

```
class RemoteSignature : IExternalSignature
    {
        private readonly byte[] signBytes;
        public RemoteSignature(byte[] signBytes)
        {
            this.signBytes = signBytes;
        }
        public virtual byte[] Sign(byte[] message)
        {
            return signBytes;
        }

        public virtual String GetHashAlgorithm()
        {
            return "SHA-256";
        }

        public virtual String GetEncryptionAlgorithm()
        {
            return "RSA";
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Maytham Fahmi. Thanks for your editing in my bad English.

Comment: Please share an example PDF signed by your code.

Comment: @mkl This folder contains my files, unsigned, temp, and signed. I used itextsharp version 5.5.13.3. Thank you https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lMnMhJOJhDpH3Jlh6N--3elWckSnjxwM?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks @mkl, I found your answer from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46243127/sign-pdf-using-itextsharp-and-xml-signature.

Comment: *"I found your answer from this post"* - Great! Shall we mark your question as duplicate of that other question then?

Comment: @mkl Of course, I'll mark it.